# org-reveal - change table font-size globally

Tags: org-mode, org-reveal

I can use below code to change font size to 60%, how can I make it take effect for all tables?

```
#+REVEAL_HTML: <div style="font-size: 60%;">
| Name                     | Blueprint        |
| LOCAL_PRODUCT_MODULE     | product_specific |
| LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE | vendor_specific  |
| LOCAL_ODM_MODULE         | device_specific  |
#+REVEAL_HTML: </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code to declare a style that will change table formatting globally:

```
#+begin_export html
<style>
.reveal  td {font-size: 60%;}
</style>
#+end_export
```

Of course you can style `th` the same way if needed.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. BTW, is REVEAL_HTML and begin_export html the same thing?

Comment: No: `#+REVEAL_HTML` is used only by `ox-reveal.el` (an exporter derived from the Org mode HTML exporter); `#+begin_export html` is recognized by the generic Org mode parser in `org-element.el`.

Comment: What the answer says is: when exporting to HTML (through either the basic HTML exporter  or one derived from it - e.g. ox-reveal.el -, add the `<style>...</style>` section to the HTML file that is produced. Any effect of the style has to do with the fact that the `ox-reveal` exporter exports  the body  as a `<div class="reveal">`, so any `<td>` element under it matches the CSS rule and gets the specified font size.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for these very clear explanations. My answer was based on an empirical approach (trials / errors) and it is really useful to have a deeper understanding.